# Flexbox: how to keep child button padding from extending past the end of the box?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using a div with `display:flex;` and no wrapping to stretch a single text input tag to meet a single button to the right of it.  The problem is, the `<input type="button">` tag has padding that is apparently added *after* the flexbox space is divvied up, so the button ends up sticking out past the right side of the flexbox.  [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jx45h8dh/1/):

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <input placeholder="placeholder" style="flex-grow:1;flex-shrink:1;">
        <input type="button" value="Save" style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; flex-shrink:0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

(the fiddle has extra styles set to show where the button is sticking out)

If I use the inspector to remove the padding, the save button fits.  What am I missing in the CSS to get the button's padding to apply *before* dividing the space, so that everything fits inside the div?  I'm unable to find anything even discussing this issue (the specification only mentions a specific case for using percentage padding), but this behavior is in both Firefox and Chrome.  I've tried wrapping the button in a div, but that did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

There's no need to apply any flex-shrink to the second input...just let it be as big as it needs to be including the padding. Then `flex:1` on the first input just tells it to take up any remaining space.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}
.left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
}
.right {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <input class="left" placeholder="placeholder" />
    <input class="right" type="button" value="Save" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems there is a difference between `flex:1` and `flex-grow:1` that causes this behavior in the text input, but I can't for the life of me figure out why since the first position in the `flex` shorthand attribute is supposed to be `flex-grow`.

Comment: You can use `flex-grow:1` but you need to set `flex-basis:0`  - https://jsfiddle.net/wp6ckg49/ By using `flex:1` the flex-basis is set to `auto` which (I guess) does something quite different.

Comment: Found one additional thing: it appears that firefox has a [default `min-width` for the input tag that has to be overridden in order for flex-shrink to work as expected](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1088586) if the div isn't wide enough.

Comment: It seems that, at least on the current version of Firefox, the `flex: 1` is not necessary, and @DerfK's answer was the only problem for me. Unless maybe Bootstrap 3 already normalizes some `flexbox` problems? Chrome & (surprisingly) IE were both fine.